# How many ways are there to arrange $3$ men, $3$ women, $3$ children in a circle such that they alternate clockwise in this order: man, woman, child?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Problem**
How many ways are there to arrange $3$ men, $3$ women, $3$ children in a circle such that they alternate clockwise in this order: man, woman, child? The seats are not numbered.

**My Opinion**
I wish to clarify this working

- Arrange $3$ men in a circle takes $(3-1)! = 2$ ways
- Arrange $3$ women next to men takes $3! = 6$ ways
- Arrange $3$ children next to women takes $3! = 6$ ways

Total $= 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 72$ ways

Please Comment if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: Are the seats numbered ?

Comment: I agree with @trueblueanil that the question of seat numbering is relevant.  However, if the problem composer omitted any detail regarding seat numbering, then it seems reasonable to infer that the seats are indistinguishable from each other.  I think that **Meta-Cheating**, where you try to enter the mind of the problem composer, in and of itself, is inconclusive here.  It is true that normally, when a table is designated as round, one expects rotations to not be relevant.  ...see next comment

Comment: However, here, the problem composer might have specified that the table is round, to facilitate the consideration of the men,women,children being in alternating order, all around the table.

Comment: Your answer appears to be correct if rotations are considered indistinguishable: I would say there are $6$ ways to order each group, for a total of $216$ orders for a line where we start with a man, and because each order in a circle corresponds with three such lines, there are $216 / 3 = 72$ orders on the circle which are rotationally distinct. But if rotating an order makes it distinct, then that could increase the number of orders by a factor of $3$ if the seats are pre-gender-assigned or $9$ if they are not. So the question is underdefined, but I think your answer is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies /\/\/\
The seats are not numbered.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.